# Range of the union of two sets of integers

Tags: statistics, elementary-set-theory, order-statistics

There are two sets of positive integers, $A$ and $B$. Let the range of $A$ be $230$ and range of $B$ be $310$, then what the range of $A \cup B$ must be at least?

---

I think the range of the union must be at least 310, i.e., $\max\{ran(A), ran(B)\}$, but I'm not too sure how to convince myself of this. Could anyone provide a general proof?

EDIT: The range of a finite set $P$ of positive integers is defined as 
$$ran(P) = \max(P) - \min(P).$$

Comment: What do you mean by "range"?

Comment: Please see edit. Thanks.

Comment: $ran(A)$ is not well-defined in your question unless the elements in $A$ are ordered.

Comment: Sorry, I re-edited the question, it's defined as the max minus the min. I forgot to mention that the set was ordered in my previous definition, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @Jack Why did you add the tag  algebra-precalculus?

Comment: @amWhy: As now OP has already given a clear definition of $ran(A)$, I think the question is mostly not about set theory. Moreover,  $ran(A)$ has nothing to do with the cardinality of $A$ now according to the definition.

Comment: @amWhy: I think what OP is really asking is about "range" in statistics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_(statistics)

Comment: @TrueTears: If you defined $ran(A)$ as $\max(A)-\min(A)$, then you don't need to the elements in $A$ to be ordered.

Comment: It was the OP that tagged this as "elementary set theory", while not tagging "statistics". Since the OP failed to provide any context for the problem, save for the action of tagging as elem.set-theory, my answer is quite appropriate. Three hours after posting the original, the OP redefined what the "range of a set" means. Before assuming this emerged in a stats problem, wait until (if ever) the OP clarifies/provides the context.

Comment: @Jack  So let $A = \{a, c, f, z, n, m, b, y, d, x\}$ which is not an ordered set, then what is the maximum and/or minimum of this set.  Given the OP's definition of range, this $\operatorname{range}$ is a function only on numbers.

Comment: @amWhy: OP states at the very beginning that "There are two sets of *positive integers*", which I consider as the context of his question. I would agree with you that the tag `elementary-set-theory` is quite confusing.

Comment: If $A=\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ were ordered so that $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_n$, then it makes sense to define $ran(A)=a_n-a_1$, which is the OP's original definition.

Comment: @Jack I have no issue with you. please put the responsibility of posting an an unclear question, unclear tag...ON THE OP! And leave it to him/her to retag, or verify the speculations you've posted as comments to my answer. If you have any further questions ask in the thread below the question.  If you feel you need to justify your answer, post that justification in a thread below *you answer.*

Comment: @Jack, the elements of $A$ and $B$ are positive integers, so they are naturally ordered.

Comment: @AlexM.: Sure I know you are talking about a "[*partially ordered set*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partially_ordered_set)". My previous comment, "If $A=\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$ were *ordered* so that $a_1<a_2<\cdots<a_n$" means one labels the elements of $A$ so that one has a finite monotone strictly increasing sequence of integers. Perhaps a more precise way to describe such thing is use the language of "order statistics"(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic).

Comment: @Jack: Am I missing something here? Isn't the problem about the usual order on natural numbers, which is a *total* order?

Comment: @AlexM.: You are not missing anything at all and any finite set of positive integers are indeed totally ordered sets. The point is that *merely denoting a finite set of positive integers as $A=\{a_1,\cdots,a_n\}$, one cannot tell that $a_1<\cdots<a_n$, unless he explicitly claims so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct.

Denote $a_1=\min A$, $a_2=\max A$, $b_1=\min B$, $b_2=\max B$. Then 
$$
a_2-a_1=230;\quad b_2-b_1=310;
$$
and 
$$
ran(A\cup B)=\max(a_2,b_2)-\min(a_1,b_1)
$$
Consider the following cases. (Drawing a picture would be a good idea at this point.)

- $b_1>a_2$;
- $a_1>b_2$;
- $[a_1,a_2]\cap[b_1,b_2]\neq\emptyset$.

It is only in the third case that one can make $ran(A\cup B)$ small. In particular, one needs $[a_1,a_2]\subset[b_1,b_2]$.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE**

This answer was posted three hours before the asker changed/edited their original question. The answer is relevant, however, though the asker would need to translate into the language of "range".

I think you mean to say that $|A| = 230, \; |B| = 310$ where $|A|$ means the cardinality of $A$.  In this case (with what I'm assuming are finite sets, A, B), cardinality of a set is equal to the number of elements in the set.

(The term "range" makes sense only when talking about functions, and even then, the term is not universally used; more standard when referring to $f: X\to Y$, we have the *domain* of $f$ as $X$, and *codomain* of $f$ being $Y$, and refer to the *image* of a function as the image of $f$ in $Y$, often denoted as $f(X)$: the set of elements $$\{f(x)\mid x\in X\}\subseteq Y$$

---

$|A\cup B|$ (the number of elements in $A\cup B$), can be found using the following: $$|A\cup B| = |A|+|B| - |A\cap B|\tag 1$$  Unless you know what elements, if any, that A and B share, i.e. $A\cap B$, I'll assume that this information was not provided, so you'll have just:

$$|A\cup B| = 230+310 - |A\cap B|\tag{2}$$

Now we'll try to find the minimum, and maximum values for $|A\cup B|$

Let's start with the maximum number of elements in $A\cup B$. From $(1), (2),$ the greatest number of elements in the set is $230 + 310 =540,$ which happens when  $A\cap B = \varnothing$.

$|A\cup B|$ is least when $A\subset B$. That is, every element in $A$ is also in $B$, and so $|A\cap B| = 230$.  In this case $|A\cup B| = 310 - 230 = 80.$ So $$|A\cup B| \geq 80.$$

Comment: According to what he/she put in the question, it is not about cardinality of a set.

Comment: If that's the case, @Jack, then by op's definition, what does it this mean with respect to the following.  $$\operatorname{range}\{\text{elephant, banana, table, light, blue, zebra, bracelet, pipe, car, house, sky, skis, waterfall, turkey}\}.$$  Answer: $\text{turkey} - \text{elephant}$

Comment: It is very possible that the OP meant: Let $A = \{a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n\}$, where the index $1\leq i \leq  n,\; i\in \mathbb N$, and $ran(A) = n -1$.

Comment: Sure, I agree with you. It is said in the beginning that $A$ and $B$ are two sets of positive integers. But his definition is ill-defined. You gave a very reasonable guess of what the question is really asking about. `:-)`

Comment: Sorry, I've re-edited the question, apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Please make sure you are clear about the question you want to ask, *before posting it."  That is, Questions are not meant to be "works in progress.  And be prepared to stick around fter posting, at least long enough to respond to folks asking for you to clarify your question.  I'm not happy that it seems I may have wasted allthe time I put into answer your original question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_U=\max A, \;a_L=\min A,\; b_U=\max B, \;b_L=\min B.\;$ Let $C=\{a_U,a_L,b_U,b_L\}.$

Since $C\subset    A\cup B$ we have $\max A\cup B \geq \max C\geq b_U$ and $\min A\cup B\leq \min C\leq b_L,$ so $\max A\cup B-\min A\cup B\geq b_U-b_L.$ Similarly, $\max A\cup B\geq  \max C\geq a_U$ and $\min A\cup B\leq \min C\leq a_L$ so $\max A\cup B-\min A\cup B\geq a_U-a_L.$